# JMS Connection problems in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, oracle, tomcat, jdbc

I'm trying to port an old,large, Weblogic-based application to Tomcat. The application uses Spring, EclipseLink, and an Oracle database.

There are two different database connections, both almost identical. The connectivity to the JSF pages work fine. Unfortunately the one to the JMS (Oracle AQ) doesn't. Here's the error I'm getting:

> myapp    | 17:17:34,177 ERROR XmlMessageListenerContainer.refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'SPFR_EVENT_Q' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=4, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Error creating the db_connection; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy51 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection

Here is the relevant connection:

```
<Resource
   name="jdbc/myAQDS"
   auth="Container"
   type="javax.sql.DataSource"
   factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
   driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
   url="jdbc:oracle:thin:theurlhere"
   username="theuser"
   password="thepassword"
   maxTotal="150"
   maxIdle="10"
 />
```

Any ideas what's causing this? I googled for the specific error, and came up completely empty handed.

Comment: There isn't much to go on here, but all I can really do is to speculate that somewhere in your application (possibly in a library) is some code that assumes the database connection to be an `oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection`.  However, this assumption fails because the connection it is being given is some proxy object.  You mention Spring: is it possible that your app is applying AOP by using JDK dynamic proxies?  Have you tried using a CGLIB proxy for the database connection instead?

Comment: This question is very confusing. JMS is not a database. The Config is for a database. The error message clearly indicates both a JMS failure and a database root cause. Perhaps the JMS broker (or server) is using Oracle under the covers, and it's only a coincidence that you have an Oracle database connection configured in your own application?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Spring documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/old-docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/orcl.streamsaq.html
Specifically the section about the NativeJdbcExtractor as there's an OracleJdbc4NativeJdbcExtractor available.

Specifically, bear in mind that the Oracle AQ connection factory needs the native Oracle connection object. However, the app server most likely wraps the dataSource connection object. Therefore, try using the OracleJdbc4NativeJdbcExtractor as the nativeJdbcExtractor of your JMS connection factory, which will be used to unwrap the connection and keep the Oracle library happy.